# Python - A magic number that is equal to all numbers?

Tags: python, equality

I need some magic number in Python that is equal to all numbers so that

```
magic_num == 20
magic_num == 300
magic_num == 10
magic_num == -40
```

I don't expect such a thing to exists but maybe is there another way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to check if the right-side expression is a number? https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric

Comment: @ShubhamSharma: `str.isnumeric` is a nigh useless function; it's checking for number-like strings, but it can't actually recognize all strings parseable as numbers. Usually, you don't want to be working with strings anyway, just type checking; the ABCs from the `numbers` module handle that case.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yeah, that's right! Although I wonder what would be the original motivation for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a class that compares equal to any numeric type if you really want to:

```
import numbers

class MagicNum:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, numbers.Number)
        # To compare equal to other magic numbers too:
        return isinstance(other, (numbers.Number, MagicNum))
```

then make an instance:

```
magic_num = MagicNum()
```

I'm not sure why you'd *want* to do this (I suspect [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040)), but it's allowed.

If you need to handle other comparisons, you can override them in whatever way makes sense for your case, e.g. to say it's equal to all numbers, but not less than or greater than them you could do:

```
class MagicNum:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, numbers.Number)
        # To compare equal to other magic numbers too:
        return isinstance(other, (numbers.Number, MagicNum))
    __le__ = __ge__ = __eq__
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return False
    __gt__ = __lt__
```

Comment: why is the numbers library needed? Also it seems to be a dead project, which makes me want to avoid it. https://github.com/jeanpimentel/numbers

Comment: @Vader: We're not talking about a third party package; `numbers` is [the built-in module that contains the numeric tower ABCs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html). `numbers.Number` is a virtual superclass of all numeric types (`int`, `float`, `complex`, `fractions.Fraction`, `decimal.Decimal`, etc. all register as subclasses of it).

Comment: Regarding the XY problem, not sure if it is but maybe you can tell me. I have a data set of wind direction over time. At some points when the wind speedis very low, when that is the case, the wind direction is irrelevant. So when I compare yesterdays wind to the wind of today and both of them were low wind speed I want to say that they are same same.

Comment: @Vader: Can you just flush sufficiently low values to 0? `if windspeed < LOW_THRESHOLD: windspeed = 0`.

Comment: I could, but I am more focused on wind direction than wind speed. It just that wind direction when wind speed is low, is a special case.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
class SuperInt(int): 
     def __eq__(self, other):
         # This is not the correct approach, but I'm leaving it as it's what
         # I wrote. ShadowRanger's answer is better given your requirement of
         # matching any number.
         return True 

x = 5
y = SuperInt(3)
print(x == y) # -> True
print(x != y) # -> True
print(y != 3) # -> False
```

Note the last two may not be what you want so you may need to override `__ne__` as well. Not to mention the other [comparison methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__).